# How to start an application with SCDF in a defined port

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

How do I start an application with SCDF in a defined port. I tried passing the property "deployer.myapp.local.javaOpts":"-Dserver.port=11111", but the pipeline is not being deployed now.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the javaOpts option to set the `server.port`. It can be set as an application property.

Something like "app.myapp.server.port= 11111" when deploying the stream.